# VBA invalid procedure call or argument while moving files

Tags: vba

I am trying to write move pdf files from one folder to another but i am getting error wile moving large name files

example:-

```
MyFile1 = Dwdname
Do While Fname <> ""
Name oldpath & Dwdname As newpath & MyFile1
    Fname = ""
Loop
```

example of file name=043661202.2016051213800476.20160513.pdf

Comment: What is `Dwdname`?, please post more code

Comment: There is a limit of 255 caracters for file paths in windows. maybe you are hitting that limit (the 255 carater is for the FULL path like `c:\...\foo.pdf`)

Comment: dwdname is file name but its only 40 characters

Comment: What about the FULL path, `newPath & MyFile1`